# Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$leave_type_name in Laravel

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel-5.8 projects I have two models: HrLeaveType and HrLeaveRequest

Model:

```
class HrLeaveType extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'hr_leave_types';

    protected $fillable = [
                  'leave_type_name',
                  'no_of_days',
                  'leave_type_code',
              ];


    public function leaverequest(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Hr\HrLeaveRequest');
    }  
}



class HrLeaveRequest extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'hr_leave_requests';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $fillable = [
                  'id',
                  'employee_id',
                  'department_id',
                   'leave_type_id',
                  'reason',
                  'line_manager_comment',
              ];


    public function leavetype()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Hr\HrLeaveType','leave_type_id');
    }
}
```

Employee Make several leave requests.

If the Leave Type is Annual or Annual Leave or annual leave the application should follow the condition in the controller below. But the issue is, we cannot say that the leave_type_id for the Annual Leave will be 1.

HrLeave Type have two fields: id (auto-increment) and leave_type_name (varchar)

### id    |  leave_type_name

1     |   Annual Leave

2     |   Maternity Leave

3     |    Sick Leave

But may not be in this order

Controller

```
      public function leave_request_approve(Request $request, $id)
      {
         $leaverequest               = HrLeaveRequest::find($id);

        if ($leaverequest->leavetype()->leave_type_name == 'Annual' || $leaverequest->leavetype()->leave_type_name == 'Annual Leave')
        {                                    
            $leaverequest->line_manager_comment    = $request->line_manager_comment;
            $leaverequest->save();
                  
            HrEmployee::where('user_id', $leaverequest->employee_id)->update([
                'on_leave' => 1
            ]);                                                         
            
        }
    }
```

Since the user can't  determine if Annual Leave is carrying the leave_type_id as 1, Instead of

```
 if ($leaverequest->leave_type_id == 1)
```

I used

```
if ($leaverequest->leavetype()->leave_type_name == 'Annual' || $leaverequest->leavetype()->leave_type_name == 'Annual Leave')
```

When I submitted, I got this error:

> #message: "Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$leave_type_name"

How do I resolve it?

Thank you

Comment: you're getting the query builder by calling the method `$leaverequest->leavetype()`, you need to call the relation result with `$leaverequest->leavetype` so `$leaverequest->leavetype->leave_type_name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$leaveType = $leaverequest->leavetype;
if ($leaveType && ($leaveType->leave_type_name == 'Annual' || $leaveType->leave_type_name == 'Annual Leave'))
```

Side note: It's better to have these strings 'Annual' & 'Annual Leave' as constants or Enums.